# Remove array from result using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Looking on how to remove array

My PHP Code :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include('./db_connect.php');

if( isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userstatus WHERE user_statusID = '".$_GET["id"]."'";
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arr_data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($arr_data,$row);
  }
}
else {
  $arr_data = null;
}
echo json_encode($arr_data);
$conn->close();
```

and result is :

[{"user_statusID":"1","status":"Admin"}]

i need to remove

**"["**{"user_statusID":"1","status":"Admin"}**"]"**

When Single row result is :

how I can do that

Comment: you have multiple rows, it has to be an array. btw your code is open sql injection

Comment: when single row is result like this
[{"user_statusID":"1","status":"Admin"}]

Comment: yes , as lawrence said you code is open to sql injection , make post and use if ( is_numeric($id) == true) , and verify it with https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/scan-sql-injection-online/

Comment: that's happens because you are making push of an array in array

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid changing the API to sometimes return an array and sometimes not, else you would need to do some check in the consumer/client-side which checks if is array of objects or just a single object which could get messy.

Though to answer you can fetch_all rows, then do a simple `if` check to see if its only one row, if it is, then apply that single row back to `$arr_data`.

```
$arr_data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $arr_data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  if (count($arr_data) === 1) $arr_data = $arr_data[0];
}
```

Also, avoid using `null` as a response as again within the consumer of this script it would need to check if its null, not an array or a single object, (3 checks because is not a normalised response).

---

**Obligatory note:** You should fix the sql injection, see this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

---

Note, this answers the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64596552/1), my answer doesn't address the new bug introduced where `$sql` is undefined and no query is supplied.